# Get token list from connected solana wallet and create an array

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

I'm trying to figure out how to take the connected wallet, from the solana wallet-adapter and grab all the spl-tokens (NFTs specifically but that filter doesn't have to happen) and create an array with the token mint addresses.  I'm fairly new to coding in general, so please bear with me.  I was able to grab the wallet address (publickey) just fine, but cannot seem to get the token addresses from that wallet.  I'm currently working in react with typescript files.

I've tried going through the Moralis Solana API https://docs.moralis.io/moralis-dapp/solana-sdk/account
but wasn't returning anything even when logging to the console.  I also had some type problems, but I believe I worked those out.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use this

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTokenAccountsByOwner

or this

https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#getTokenLargestAccounts